# Implementing a python merge sort algorithm into Go

Tags: python, algorithm, go, mergesort

I'm going through the book `Learning Algorithms` by George Heineman. The in-book examples are all in Python, and up to now I've had no trouble translating them into Go, until I encountered the merge-sort algorithm.

Here is the code I came up with (see on [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/aWhthu75A0v):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func mergeSort(a []int) {
    aux := make([]int, len(a))

    merge := func(low, mid, high int) {
        copy(aux[low:high+1], a[low:high+1])

        left, right := low, mid+1

        for i := range aux[low : high+1] {
            switch {
            case left > mid:
                a[i] = aux[right]
                right++
            case right > high:
                a[i] = aux[left]
                left++
            case aux[right] < aux[left]:
                a[i] = aux[right]
                right++
            default:
                a[i] = aux[left]
                left++
            }
        }
    }

    var rsort func(int, int)
    rsort = func(low, high int) {
        if high <= low {
            return
        }
        mid := (low + high) / 2

        rsort(low, mid)
        rsort(mid+1, high)
        merge(low, mid, high)
    }

    rsort(0, len(a)-1)
}

func main() {
    array := []int{4, 76, 3, 223, 90, 69, 98, 75, 62}
    fmt.Println(array)

    mergeSort(array)
    fmt.Println(array)
}
```

I'm at a bit of a loss why it's not working, and have tried tweaking a few of the properties.

For reference, here is the original Python code: https://github.com/heineman/LearningAlgorithms/blob/main/ch05/merge.py#L5

Comment: `for i := range aux[low : high+1]` is not the same as `for i in range(lo, hi+1):`.    Use `for i := low; i < high+1; i++ {`.

Comment: wow i feel really dumb now haha. Thank you so much!!!